# Get returned bool value via WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, return

**EDIT:** I keep getting the error: cannot await void. My login method is bool, but VS says its void. I created a new project inserted only the code below and updated service reference - doesn't help. Here is a WP code:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WCFserviceReference.Service1Client proxy = new WCFserviceReference.Service1Client();

        bool returnStr = await proxy.loginAsync(passTxtBx.Text, loginTxtBx.Text);
        if (returnStr == true)
        {
            PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["UserName"] = loginTxtBx.Text;
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/usrPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
        else MessageBox.Show("Invalid user credentials");
    }
```

Here is my Service Contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool login(string usn, string pwd);
}
```

And service implementation:

```
 public bool login(string usn, string pwd)
        {
            DataClasses1DataContext auth = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            var message = from p in auth.Users
                          where p.usrName == usn && p.usrPass == pwd
                          select p;
            if (message.Count() > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

It is not void, isn't it? So what is wrong?

Here is Client generated proxy:

```
public partial class Service1Client : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<PhoneApp.WCFserviceReference.IService1>, PhoneApp.WCFserviceReference.IService1 {

    private BeginOperationDelegate onBeginloginDelegate;
    private EndOperationDelegate onEndloginDelegate;
    private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback onloginCompletedDelegate;
    private BeginOperationDelegate onBeginOpenDelegate;
    private EndOperationDelegate onEndOpenDelegate;
    private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback onOpenCompletedDelegate;
    private BeginOperationDelegate onBeginCloseDelegate;
    private EndOperationDelegate onEndCloseDelegate;
    private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback onCloseCompletedDelegate;
    public Service1Client() {
    }

    public Service1Client(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName) {
    }

    public Service1Client(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public Service1Client(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public Service1Client(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress) {
    }
```

When I point mouse on the `proxy.loginAsync(passTxtBx.Text, loginTxtBx.Text);` it says: `void Service1Client.loginAsync(string usn, string pwd) (+1 overload(s))`

Comment: What errors are you getting? How can we possible help unless you tell us that at least?

Comment: Sorry, I added what errors I'm getting.

Comment: OK errors 2 and 3 are because 

    if returnStr == true

needs to be 

    if (returnStr == true)

Answer (score 0):

Update you service reference and after your proxy is up to date, then this should work:

```
private async void loginBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WCFserviceReference.WCFserviceClient proxy = new WCFserviceReference.WCFserviceClient();

    bool returnStr = await proxy.loginAsync(passTxtBx.Text, loginTxtBx.Text);
    if (returnStr == true)
    {
        PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["UserName"] = loginTxtBx.Text;
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/usrPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
    else MessageBox.Show("Invalid user credentials");
}
```

**EDIT:**

Make sure, the method on server side is decorated by [OperationContract] attribute:

```
[OperationContract]
public bool login(string usn, string pwd)
{
    DataClasses1DataContext auth = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    var message = from p in auth.Users
                    where p.usrName == usn && p.usrPass == pwd
                    select p;
    if (message.Count() > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

In your client proxy is no login nor loginAsync method. I don't know if you are familiar with webservices workflow, so there are basic steps:

- write the service project, compile and run
- "add service reference" to client project using service wsdl (service must run) and right click on project
- on every change of service, compile service project again, run it and in client project right click on service reference and select "update service reference" option.

After that you have the client up to date. So, if you have written method login on the server side, it should appear on client side too.

Comment: It doesn't work, the await method is highlighted and error says: cannot awaiw 'void'.

Comment: Then loginAsync is not bool (Task<bool>) returning method. Update service reference, or try to use synchronous method proxy.login (then remove async and await keywords).

Comment: When I remove async and await - error: cannot implicitly convert void to bool. And when I make method bool(Task<bool>), error: cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'system.threading.tasks.task bool'. Which way is the best to solve this?

Comment: Yes, I did. And still can't await void.

Comment: You have something wrong. This should not be void but bool. Check your service again, compile and then update its reference again.

Comment: I think it is because of the errors in the WCF service it can't be updated properly. Do you know how to correct mistake where returned false and true values are highlighted and it says: cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'system.threading.tasks.task bool'.
Because I created a new project and inserted only that service implementation - WCF service reference wasn't updating since I've got that errors.

Comment: Post somewhere whole service class.

Comment: I edited the question. Created a new project and put only that code there to test where is a problem. Maybe there is other way around I can implement user authorization?

Comment: Please, show also client generated proxy. I don't see anything wrong in given code.